# iOS Safari keeps snapping back to location or zoom size

Tags: ios, safari

Safari (iPad 6, latest OS) has started doing this weird thing.

- If you try to zoom, or conspicuously, un-zoom, Safari zooms but then "blinks" and snaps back to the previous size.
- If you try to scroll down, Safari "blinks" then snaps back to the top of the screen.

The blinks are as fast as an eye blink.  As you repeat the action, it will do these things over and over.

- You'll be writing a question or answer, and Safari "blinks" and suddenly it has reverted to the last save-point.

Is this Safari quickly rebooting? What is going on? Is this a rapid and silent version of a Safari "A page error occurred, Safari had to reload the page" type error?

This new iPad is notably and dramatically faster to render pages than my old one.  Is the message just going by *that fast*?